# Highlight menu item depending on anchor selected?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the following tutorial to create a one page website:
http://www.insitedesignlab.com/how-to-make-a-single-page-website/

Is it possible to change the color of the menu item depending on what anchor is selected?

This is how I've setup the menu

```
        <?php $current = $post->ID; $counter = 1; $mypages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
            foreach( $mypages as $page ) { ?>
            <?php if ($current == $page->ID) { ?>
                <li><a style="color:white!IMPORTANT;" id="menu<?php echo $counter; ?>" href="#section<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <li><a id="menu<?php echo $counter; ?>" href="#section<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php $counter++; } ?>
```

So each menu iterates by 1 each time it loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Jquery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)... Maybe its easier

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without using another plugin?

Comment: You can, but this is clean code... You can do it with regular jquery... But... to much code..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I think the right approach here is to bind the tabs, I mean not depending in the anchor, so everytime a tab is clicked it will change,so first you have to add a class to all tabs like so:

```
<li><a style="color:white!IMPORTANT;" id="menu<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="tab" href="#section<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></li>
```

after that you just need to bind the tab elements to the click function to fire the event every time a tab is selected:

```
$(".tab").click(function(e){
     $(".tab").css("color", ""); //Remove the color from all tabs
     $(this).css("color", "white!IMPORTANT"); //Apply the "highlight" color to the selected
});
```

this way we remove the color from all "tab" elements, and then we apply the color to the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use a css class for the link that you want to be highlighted.

CSS:

```
.linkactive{
color:pink;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#nav a").click(){
  $(".linkactive").removeClass("linkactive");
  $(this).addClass("linkactive");
});
```

Please remember to add the class "linkactive" to your home or starting tab.